# Dynamically disable the web toolbar and profiler in Symfony 4 using .env

Tags: symfony, symfony4

The web profiler is set to activate if `APP_ENV` is `dev`. It is this way on our staging server; however, a security audit is being run on our staging server and it is required that we manually turn the profiler off while keeping `APP_ENV` = `dev`.

**This will successfully disable the profiler and toolbar:**

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

framework:
    profiler: 
      { enabled: false, only_exceptions: false }
```

But I want to use `.env` to use flags that we can control to disable each. When I try to, Symfony complains:

`Environment variables "bool:SYMFONY_TOOLBAR" are never used. Please, check your container's configuration.`

This leads me to an answer [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27526), which claims:

> `profiler > enabled` cannot be set with a runtime env variable, because that controls whether all the profiler services are created in the container (wrapping services whenever needed to be able to profile them). Changing the container entirely cannot be done at runtime (and the value of this boolean config does not end up being set itself anywhere in the container, which is why this error is triggered)

The developer says "Use a parameter in a file that is only loaded in dev mode." but I have no idea what that means; so, how can I resolve this? (.env is not a requirement, just ideal)

Comment: What do you mean you need your environment to be `dev`? Needs the environment to be called that `dev`? You need to have `dev` packages installed? Please, be a bit more specific regarding your requirements.

Comment: To follow up on what @yivi is suggesting, make yourself a staging environment and adjust things accordingly.

Comment: Hi guys, APP_ENV is built to use value `dev` for development as seen here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/configuration/environments.html But the problem is we do have a staging server: I just need to disable the web profiler and profiler with a flag while on the staging server. But I cannot seem to get that working. Of course I could just push hardcoded `false` values, but that would require manually changing our repository, rather than our `.gitignore`'d .env file.

Comment: But do you need to environment to be called "dev"? Can't you create a different environment for staging? E.g. `APP_ENV=staging`. Don't just repeat you want it to "use value `dev`", please explain what do you need this configuration to mean for this environment. Also, if you do not ping the other users, we won't know you commented here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to use environment flags in `web_profiler.yaml` due to the order in which the framework loads its environment variables. Thankfully it isn't too hard or scary to just make a new environment:

https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/configuration/environments.html#creating-a-new-environment

Create your environment, save your new `web_profiler.yaml` under it, then add it to `bundles.php`'s relevant lines; in my case, my line reads like this after adding the **staging** environment:

`Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true, 'staging' => true],`